# Processing XML with XSLT and CSS in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xslt

I have an issue that I presume should be simple to fix but I just can't seem to find a solution. I have an xml file I want to display. For that, I am currently using an XSLT file to do that. Now, I just changed my CSS from embedded in the XSLT for a CSS file instead, which is better since I will be able to use the same CSS file for multiple XSLT files.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:tools="tools">
        <xsl:include href="AnotherXSLT.xsl" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
            <head>
                <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" MEDIA="screen" >
            </head>
            <body>
                ...
            </body>
        </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I mean, it cannot be more simple as a stylesheet. But when it is processed, Internet Explorer gives me this error:

```
End tag 'head' does not match the start tag 'link'. Error processing resource     
'file:///C:/Users/...
      </head>
--------^
```

I tried closing the link tag this way:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" MEDIA="screen" />
```

Then I simply get : End tag 'html' does not match the start tag 'LINK'.

I also tried to put a DOCTYPE before the `<html>` tag inside the template, I get another error saying I cannot place a doctype after a proclog or something.

Any ideas?

As requested, this is my CSS:
    body
    {
      font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
      font-size:0.8em;
    }
    table.mono
    {
      font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
      font-size:0.85em;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table.solidblack, th.solidblack, td.solidblack
    {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    span
    {
      font-size:inherit;
      display:inline-block;
      padding-left:16px;
    }
    td.padding, th.padding
    {
      padding-left:16px;
      padding-right:16px;
    }
    h3.exp
    {
      display:inline;
      padding-left:6px;
    }

Comment: Assuming it is not too late, could you provide the xslt file "AnotherXSLT.xsl" which is included in your main xsl?

Answer (score 2):

We need to see the lines around your CSS include. Thank you.

Edit : By the way, with or without your XSLT, I can assume you forgot the last trailing slash in your  :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

At the end, look the "**/**".

Comment: yeah, the error definitely points to a link tag that has been left unclosed, so, sebastien's answer is almost certainly the solution to this particular problem, though there may be others.